# My program that converted 26 letters into ascII did not show me right answer

Tags: c++

Here is my part code:
I guess there is something wrong with my 3rd line code. But I can not figure it out.

```
char letter1{'a'};
    while(letter1 <= 'z') {
        std::cout << letter1<<'  '<< static_cast<int>(letter1)<<'\n';
        ++letter1;
    }
```

[Here is my screenshot for program result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdMaA.png)

Comment: Curious what your compiler makes of two spaces in single quotes. That used to be a common extension on MacOS compilers. There's probably a warning that you should turn on.

Comment: Single quotes are for single characters, while you try to put two. Use `"` double quotes for `"  "`. It's strange that it even compiles

Comment: I use code:: blocks on windows 10

Comment: I tried to use "  " instead of '  '. It showed the right answer.  I misused ' ' and " ".

Comment: @KMING `' '` should also work fine. The problem was typing `'  '` **two** spaces inside single quotes. If you had your warnings turned on then you may have got something similar to `warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a double space here `<<'  '<<`. You cannot have two characters in a character literal. Change the code to use double quotes like this

```
std::cout << letter1<<"  "<< static_cast<int>(letter1)<<'\n';
```

Or just output a single space, like this

```
std::cout << letter1<<' '<< static_cast<int>(letter1)<<'\n';
```

Comment: @KMING If this answer solved your problem consider accepting it :)